# Creating dynamic, sortable, shiftable 2d collection in Java

Tags: java, information-retrieval

The case is building [term-document matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document-term_matrix) , but here the case is row are documentIds and columns are terms.

How to achieve this using Java generic collection?
So far, I've already try this :

```
class Matrix { 
    HashMap<Point, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    Matrix(row, col, frequency) {
        map.put(new Point(row, col), frequency);
    }
}
```

where

```
class Point { Document row, Term col; }
class Document { String documentId }
class Term { String term }
```

Term is sorted alphabetically. By using those code I think it would be hard to sync every Point if there are new terms in certain Document.

So my question is, how to build collection that enable behavior like this?

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the wheel. This has all been done before. See the [Guava Table interface and implementations](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Table.html).